How do i use set variable colors to create a gradient in css?
Is there a way to use variable colors I defined in my CSS file to create a gradient effect, instead of using the regular means of redefining the colors.
var colors:
:root{
    --primary-color: #c02410;
    --primary-color-dark: #831708;
}

regular method I am aware of
background-image: linear-gradient(#c02410, #831708);


hi @Ayomikun2820 welcome to stackoverflow community please search before asking and also read How do I ask a good question? and did you check MDN-doc->variables and MDN-doc->gradient also this use-css-variables-with-rgba-for-gradient-transparency?

This question is similar to: Use CSS variables with rgba for gradient transparency. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
